GoogleSheets4 - OAuth 403 Permission Error
Currently I am developing a survey App and at the end it stores user answers inside of a .csv file. From here the goal is to upload this .csv file to the a googleSheet of the survey creator. I could just use gs4_deAuth(), then just upload the .csv result using the sheet link but that is not as secure as using OAuth on a private sheet.
As a result of using OAuth I have been running into the error below:
Error in `gs4_get_impl_()`:
! Client error: (403) PERMISSION_DENIED
• Client does not have sufficient permission. This can happen because the OAuth token does not have the right scopes, the client doesn't have permission, or the
  API has not been enabled for the client project.
• The caller does not have permission

Below is the code I attempted that resulted in the error, currently I am using a desktop OAuth, but I will eventually switch to a Webpage OAuth when the app deploys.
API <- Sys.getenv("GoogleAPI")

credentials_path <- #Removed Pathing

setup_auth <- function() {
  gs4_auth_configure(path = credentials_path)
}

setup_auth()

# Sheet ID
ssID <- "12f5iLaXlXqkWz3pWs6fLLPX6PfiiVxuQ_BzJqKfgacQ"

# Sheet Reading/Editing/Checking Section
df <- read_csv() #Removed Pathing 

# Read the sheet
Sheet <- read_sheet(ss = ssID, range = "A:A")

When the paths are put back in I get the 403 error saying I don't have permission.
Again, the API key is unrestricted and the OAuth is set for Desktop

Check this question
